# Error on Setup:install new store 2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4

I'm trying to install a new magento 2.4.5 store by CLI using this command:

```
composer create-project --repository-url=https://repo.magento.com/ magento/project-community-edition:2.4.5
```

Ok this install correctly, but when i run the setup:install command, it returns this error:

[image]

The same error happens when i run **"php bin/magento cache:flush"** and others commands. What could it be? any help is appreciated.

setup:install command:

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://loja245.local --base-url-secure=https://loja245.local --db-host=127.0.0.1 --db-name=magento --db-user=user --db-password=pass --admin-firstname=admin --admin-lastname=admin --admin-email=user@email.com --admin-user=user --admin-password=pass --language=pt_BR --currency=BRL --timezone=America/Sao_Paulo --use-rewrites=1 --search-engine=elasticsearch7 --elasticsearch-host=192.168.4.108 --elasticsearch-port=9200
```

I'm using PHP 8.1, MariaDB 10.4, mysql 8.0. Just like the adobe system requirements says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates `Fiber::getCurrent()` method is undefined, the `Fiber` class has been available since PHP 8.1, so make sure you are running at least PHP 8.1.

I see you mentioned you are using PHP 8.1 but could you double-check by running this command:

> php -v

Comment: It's running on PHP 8.1.0-dev.

Comment: I'm not sure PHP 8.1.0-dev contains `Fiber` class or not but since it has a vulnerability ('User-Agentt' Remote Code Execution). You should update your PHP version to at least 8.1.

Comment: And you had this error so we can assume PHP 8.1.0-dev does not have `Fiber` class yet.

Answer (score 0):

try removing composer.lock file and re run composer install it will fix the issue.